# What program can I use to automatically shift all other numbers when I change/add a number when writing a patent application?

Tags: number, writing, numbering, numerical-references

I have a patent application with numbered references. What program can I use to automatically shift all other numbers if I need to change/add a number?

[E.g.](https://patents.google.com/patent/US20220138425A1/en):

> FIG. 1 shows an example of a system for natural language processing according to aspects of the present disclosure. The example shown includes user **100**, user device **105**, acronym definition network **110**, cloud **155**, and database **160**. In some embodiments, acronym definition network **110** includes input sequence encoder **115**, long form encoder **120**, scoring component **125**, long form selection component **130**, sample collection component **135**, training component **140**, processor unit **145**, and memory unit **150**. In some embodiments, the components and functions of the acronym definition network **110** are located on the user device **105**.
>
> Fig. 1 (cropped, see full image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEHBD.png)):
>
> [image]

In case I have to change add one number, e.g. 100 (adding a new 100 box in the figure), what program can I  to automatically shift all other numbers (old 100 becomes 105, 105 becomes 110, etc.)?

Comment: This question is much better suited to the Software Recommendation SE site.

Comment: @EricS thanks, I wasn't sure if people had this use case commonly beyond patent writing. I was assuming patent writers had a solution for that.

Comment: Most patent lawyers I’ve worked with use Microsoft Word.

Comment: @EricS thanks! In case they have to add a figure or a box, do they manually change all affected numbers?

Comment: Yes. Some leave occasionally gaps in the numbering to make it less onerous.

Comment: I agree with other answers that SE is better suited for this question, but if you use Google Docs, and can program with rudimentary JavaScript, then Google Docs allows you to run JS on your document via _App Scripts_. I have a script to automatically (re)number each paragraph, for example.

Comment: @Drakes thanks would you be ok to share your script? If so I'll open a question on WebApps SE.

Comment: Happy to help. Here is a gist I just made for you: https://gist.github.com/ericdraken/755d36ef84f91df7df678aaebc0fa869

Answer (score 1):

I do not know a program to do that other than sed used with Unix or Unix-like systems.

However, you do not need to have monotonically increasing numbers.  Most people do what you do and initially leave gaps and then fill in intermediate numbers if changes are needed. And a convention like 100 for a whole device and 101 for parts can help readability but has no legal significance.

A compromise might be to switch some more important numbers with find/replace in Word and then put in new numbers between existing numbers.